# What is the function of "顷" in "公园里那顷莲花池内"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The quote goes as follows.

> 据说若干年前，公园里那顷莲花池内，曾经栽满了红睡莲。

English translation:

> Years ago, we were told, the lotus pond in the middle of the park was
> planted with red water lilies.

The pond is in modern day 228 Memorial Park in Taipei. The only measure word function I can find for 顷 is as an area equivalent of more than 6 hectares, which does not seem to fit here. I also guessed 顷莲花 could be a specific flower, but did not find anything to back that up.

Comment: 顷 is a unit(公顷 and 顷), but in practice, you can just treat it as a quantifier like 块,, and not necessarily related to the real geometry size.

Comment: Thank you! I can not mark the question as answered since your post is a direct reply. I'm still pretty new to this community, so I don't know if you should post another answer, or if an admin could just mark the question as answered.

Comment: Glad to help, and don't worry about that, maybe somebody has more detailed answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Baidu, 池的量词为：

组词如下：
一（汪）莲花池
一（方）莲花池
一（湾）莲花池
一（片）莲花池

[Here](https://www.pinshiwen.com/yuexie/cycd/20190904241225.html) it says:

“顷”是用于度量的物量词。
"qing" is used as a count-measure word for things.

据说若干年前，
They say, years ago
公园里那顷莲花池内，
the lotus lake in the park
曾经栽满了红睡莲。
was once full of red water lilies.

Or, the author missed out XX顷大的

人们在那建造了一个六公里长，**1248公顷大的**岛屿。

梅龙·史密斯曾在多伦多大学攻读博士学位，他和同事是在一个阔叶林里发现**15公顷大的**真菌的。

For me, 66 000 m2 is way too big for a pond, that's a lake!

Comment: As mentioned above, the most probable answer seems to be that it's a general measure word in this context. The pond can be spotted [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7b/228_Memorial_Park_Taipei.jpg) and it's certainly not very large. I will mark the question as answered.